# Managing project documents in visualstudio.com - Cannot create a document library

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to add a document repository to a new project hosted in VisualStudio.com

I can only find ways of doing it in TFS similar to that explained in the following MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181484.aspx#TE_CreatingLibrary

Is it possible to manage project documents for project hosted in visual studio?
How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242865.aspx) the project portal is not available for Visual Studio Online:

> If your team project was created using the Basic configuration or is
>   hosted on Visual Studio Online, you won’t have access to a project
>   portal.

Answer (score 0):

What do people use for project documentation then?  Would be great if there was a wiki, or a place to put documents?  Not to mention the tickets and the comments don't have a UI and you can't drag and drop screen shots.  It's just too bad that you have to use another 3rd party tool.  Maybe it's just better to use git.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the free Wiki extension (just acquired by Microsoft) for VisualStudio.com It is automatically managed then in your repo.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2017/02/08/vsts-has-acquired-wiki/